# How to count only checked items in CheckedListBox dynamically while the user is checking boxes?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox control on my windows form application, which gives a list of items to select from.
I want to count and show only checked (not selected) items while the user is still checking them. I mean count as you check them.

I have tried to use ItemCheck event and CheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count but the problem is that it counts every other click even if the item is unchecked. When I check something it counts and if I unchecked it again, it counts that too.

I think it has to do with the remark given on MSDN ["The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) I do not completely understand the problem here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ItemCheckEventArgs parameter has the Property (NewValue) which tells you whether the change is a check, uncheck or neither.

If CheckedItems.Count is not updated until after the event fires (which is what I'm understanding from that remark) - then you can add that count, and see whether the ItemChecckEventArgs is a check (+1) or an uncheck (-1) and you can get the correct total.

(Unless I'm understanding the remark wrongly, its very vague).

Comment: Thanks a lot, You understood correct. It worked after some updates in my code. I am going to post it below as a post. :-)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Haedrian answered this correctly, but i think raw code goes a long ways too. So here's the C# code:

```
private void CheckedListBox_ItemCheck(Object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int sCount = checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count;
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked  ) { ++sCount; }
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked) { --sCount; }
    // now sCount is count of selected items in checkedListBox.
}
```

I had the same issue, and this question and answer gave me the solution. Thanks for the question and already existing answers!

Answer (score 3):

Add event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` and get the count from `CheckedItems.Count`.

With `ItemCheck` you don't have the actual value, but value before the last change is processed and you would need to adjust the count according to EventArgs as Haedrian proposed.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution, not really wise but working fine. I will post it below.

Answer (score 1):

Since we won't get the updated value in the CheckedItems.Count immediately, we use `e.NewValue` to get the updated value to get whether the state is Checked or not.

Declare a global variable for getting the count

```
int chkListCount = 0;
```

In the `ItemCheck` event give the following code

```
private void chkList_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
     {
         chkListCount++;
     }
     else if(e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
     {
         chkListCount--;
     }
}
```

Its the simple logic to get the count of selected items

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a wise and intelligent work as a beginner but at the end solved my problem.

```
private void CheckedListBox_ItemCheck(Object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (e.NewValue.ToString() == "Checked")
        {
            // first get all the checked items
            foreach (object checkeditem in CheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                string checkItem = CheckedListBox.GetItemCheckState(CheckedListBox.Items.IndexOf(checkeditem)).ToString();
                if (checkItem == "Checked")
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            // Now, below is the most important part considering the remark on MSDN
            // "The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs."
            count = count + 1; // Plus 1 as the NewValue was Checked
            labelCount.Text = "You have selected " + count + "Items.";
        }
        else if (e.NewValue.ToString() == "Unchecked")
        {
            // first get all the checked items
            foreach (object checkeditem in CheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
            {
                string checkItem = CheckedListBox.GetItemCheckState(CheckedListBox.Items.IndexOf(checkeditem)).ToString();
                if (checkItem == "Checked")
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            // Now, below is the most important part considering the remark on MSDN
            // "The check state is not updated until after the ItemCheck event occurs."
            count = count - 1; // minus 1 as the NewValue was Unchecked,
            labelCount.Text = "You have Selected " + count + "Items.";
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate comments on this code.

Comment: it's better to not convert to a String and then test that string value, if you can do the same without the .ToString() method.

Comment: Looping thru each object in CheckedItems is needless since you can just get the count from the CheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count property. Plus every item in .CheckedItems will already be checked since you are already looping thru only the *Checked* Items of the CheckedListBox. All you need to do instead is grab the count and then either increment or decrement that count value by 1. It only takes three normal lines of code. Please see my separate answer with those three lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered long ago, but I found it easier to just handle the MouseUp and KeyUp events. The CheckedItems.Count property is accurate when those events are fired. Since they both do the same thing, I created a method to to the work and called that method from both event handlers.

```
    private void clbFolders_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { Update(); }
    private void clbFolders_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { Update(); }

    private void Update()
    {
        btnDelete.Enabled = clbFolders.CheckedItems.Count > 0;
    }
```